# Convert Complex Expression<Func<TDTO>,bool> to Expression<Func<TEntity>,bool>

Tags: c#, architecture, expression, n-tier-architecture

I have DTOmodel in my Framework. BLL and View do not see EntiyModel at all. I want to transfer and convert Complex Expression between layers.

this is a method in the BLL like this...

```
//// BLL(Service)
Public PersonDTO getAll(Expression<Func<PersonDTO, bool>> whereCondition)
{

   return _repository.getAll(whereCondition);

}


// DLL(Repository)

Public PersonDTO getAll(Expression<Func<PersonDTO, bool>> whereCondition)
{

   Expression<Func<Person, bool>> NewCondition = ?/ How Convert DTOwhereCondition ???

   return DataContext.Persons(NewCondition);

}
```

///// I want to create complex expression on PersonDTO like this:

```
var persons = serive.getPersons(i => i.PersonDetailsDTO.Count == 3);
```

///// My Classes

```
     public class Person
       {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public List<PersonDetail> PersonDetails { get; set; }
       }


    public class PersonDTO
      {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public List<PersonDetailDTO> PersonDetailsDTO { get; set; }
      }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're attempting to do. You might want to provide a little more information. If you have expressions as parameters, you **can** pass a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite the most basic solution. If you need more features, maybe you can work your way up from there. So far it allows to optionally provide a delegate to resolve mapped property names, but the property types have to be the same.

Usage:

```
var mappedExpression =
    ExpressionMapper<Person>.MapFrom(originalDtoExpression, null);

// or:

var mappedExpression =
    ExpressionMapper<Person>.MapFrom(originalDtoExpression,
            entityPropertyName => someMapper.ResolveDtoPropertyName(entityPropertyName));
```

Implementation:

```
public class ExpressionMapper<TTarget> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected ExpressionMapper(Type sourceType, Func<string, string> resolveTargetMemberNameFunc)
    {
        this.SourceType = sourceType;
        this.ResolveTargetMemberNameFunc = resolveTargetMemberNameFunc ?? (cur => cur);
    }

    public Func<string, string> ResolveTargetMemberNameFunc { get; private set; }

    public Type SourceType { get; private set; }

    public static Expression MapFrom<TSource>(Expression sourceExpression, Func<string, string> resolveTargetMemberNameFunc)
    {
        return new ExpressionMapper<TTarget>(typeof(TSource), resolveTargetMemberNameFunc).Visit(sourceExpression);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TTarget, bool>> MapFrom<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> sourcePredicateExpression, Func<string, string> resolveTargetMemberNameFunc)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTarget, bool>>(
                MapFrom<TSource>(sourcePredicateExpression.Body, resolveTargetMemberNameFunc),
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), sourcePredicateExpression.Parameters[0].Name));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var sourceMemberName = node.Member.Name;
        var targetNode = this.Visit(node.Expression);
        var targetMemberName = this.ResolveTargetMemberNameFunc(sourceMemberName);
        var targetMember = targetNode.Type.GetMember(targetMemberName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (targetMember == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("The source type '{0}' cannot be mapped to the target type '{1}', because that target type has no member '{2}'.", node.Expression.Type.Name, targetNode.Type.Name, targetMemberName));
        }

        return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetNode, targetMember);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == this.SourceType)
        {
            return Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), node.Name);
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. did you test this piece of code?

1- It returns Error for complex query, something like this:

    var persons = serive.getPersons(i => i.PersonDetailsDTO.Count == 3);

2- It does not work for simple query like this:

    var persons = serive.getPersons(i => i.firstName == "name");

 when i execute the WhereCondition and want to access Persons.Count(), i retrieve this Exception:

**{"The parameter 'i' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression."} System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}.**

Thanks.

Comment: As I said, this is the quite simplest approach possible that you can use as a starting point. Generally, it's very difficult and elaborate, maybe impossible to add any possible use case. If you need to implement what's missing, you'll have to learn more about expression trees. 1) Nested DTOs are definitely not supported. 2) That's how I use it all the time successfully, but without the `.Count()`. Can't say for now what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AutoMapper to convert expressions using DTOs to Entities. Expression mapping is part of AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping package. You essentially have to call AddExpressionMapping when you call AddAutoMapper (which itself is an extension method to IServiceCollection)